# Tensorflow: Int, float types not working in record_defaults

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder, tensor

I want to import various types of columns like int, float, string as tensors. Only the first record_defaults work, where all are set as strings.

But I get the error below. Is there any way to use tensorflow with various types of placeholders?

The csv file is from [aws](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aml-sample-data/banking.csv).

```
import tensorflow as tf

# https://s3.amazonaws.com/aml-sample-data/banking.csv
file1="/Users/Q/Downloads/banking.csv"
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file1])
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# record_defaults = [[""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [0]]
# record_defaults = [[0], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [0], [0], [0], [0], [""], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0]]
record_defaults = [[0], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [0]]

cols = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim=",")

features = tf.stack(cols[:-1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1000):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, cols[-1]])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Error message

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/Q/Dropbox/code/Analyzing-Tea/tf-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Q/Dropbox/code/Analyzing-Tea/tf-test.py", line 14, in <module>
    features = tf.stack(cols[:-1])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 715, in stack
    return gen_array_ops._pack(values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1975, in _pack
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Pack", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 463, in apply_op
    raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [int32, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string] that don't all match.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this line: `features = tf.stack(cols[:-1])`. It tries to stack all the feature column tensors into a single tensor, which will only work if they are of the same type (and the type is deduced from the record default value).

So don't stack them all and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, @alexandre-passos! I thought the error message "that don't all match" meant I gave the wrong type of a certain column, but it meant that all columns should have the same type.

Comment: Yes, if you want to concatenate all columns in a single tensor (tf.stack) then they need to have the same type.

Comment: for handling csv files according to this documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data we need to put all features together, if they are of different type, how do we handle them ?

Comment: You need to first turn all features into floating point numbers. See the [tensorflow feature columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column) for an API to do this easily.